# Will this roof vent installation cause me problems?

Tags: roof, vent, exhaust-fan, exhaust-vent

I just have my house re-roofed on last November. Recently I look around in the attic and found the new vents and ventilation fan weren't prefect fit the existing holes. Will this situation be a big problem? And is that normal for the exhaust full of felt?

The fan was installed like the exhaust- a quarter vent block by the plywood, half of the base left blank.

Update some picture

[image: the off-center vent]
[image: Another vent, looks fine]
[image: Off-center Fan]
[image: From outside]

Comment: I can't imagine how felt would've ended up at the upper portion of that device. More clarity is needed here. The slight offset isn't a serious problem. It may have been done to better fit the shingles above or some obstruction. Assuming they aren't _all_ partially obstructed it's no big deal. I would not mess with the roofing to fix it.

Comment: We can see blue roofing underlayment around the opening. I don't think what we see in the vent cap is roofing felt. For one thing it looks very fibrous. I wonder if it's not the structure of the vent itself. Again, more clarity is needed.

Comment: Is this a passive vent or an active fan?

Comment: @FreeMan Thank you for your interpretation. Yes what I mean is exactly what you said. Sorry for my bad grammar

Comment: No worries! Your English is _far_ better than my version of your native tongue.

Comment: This is a passive vent, and the active fan have same issue, but I took a blurry picture, so I will take a clear photo for the fan and update later.

Comment: @isherwood Yeah the material is very fibrous. I will try to tear it a little bit to see if it is the structure of the vent itself. The problem for a newbie like me is I never saw what the parts looks like when it on the shelf of Homedepot or Lowe's, hence I don't know if the right thing on my roof in the right way LOL.

Comment: You need to remove the felt that is inside the round part of the vent. Otherwise it, from here, looks fine. I assume this photo is upside down in terms of the slope of the roof — that the roof pitches towards “up” in the photo.

Comment: The only thing other than the felt paper is the vent seems very off center. You want to make sure the flange of the vent covers all the sides well, you don’t want any part of the hole in the sheathing to be protected only by a small amount of flashing.

Comment: @RibaldEddie, you're right. That's the ridge beam at the _bottom_ of the image. Unfortunately, I've rotated the image and it's just as confusing that way...

Comment: I don't see any vent fasteners coming through the sheathing - are there any? Photos of what this looks like from on top of the roof would be very helpful - I wonder if it was flashed properly.

Comment: @Armand Good hint. I will take more photos from outside when weather allowed.